# Flash videos turn to gray box with light gradients on edges

Tags: linux, opensuse, nvidia, adobe-flash, chrome

It started happenning since installation of new openSUSE and it looks quite bizarre, see below for a shot from blip.tv.
[image: bizarre]

It happens usually after few minutes of watching a video, sometimes sooner, sometimes later. It happens also on Youtube. Any ideas? I would like to retain hardware acceleration so I do not accept solutions disabling it.

To add more details about my setup. Laptop is a Thinkpad T420 with NVIDIA Quadro NVS 4200M, hooked up to double monitors via docking station.

Comment: Providing the video card's model and nvidia driver version would be useful.